# How can I convert VARCHAR string value in Python to a float?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, finance

I am web scraping stock prices from Yahoo Finance, but the value is coming in as the following:

"3,099.00"

This value is being read as a string. How do I remove the comma, and then convert the value to a float?

The ultimate goal is to store this value in Postgres as a FLOAT.

The value that holds this string is as follows:

```
price = soup.find('span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)').text
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html) module for this

```
import locale

price = "3,099.00"
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') 
price = locale.atof(price)

print(price, type(price))
>>> 3099.0 <class 'float'>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace it like this:

```
float(price.replace(',',''))
```

Comment: This will result in unfortunate results in locales where `.` is the thousand separator - that's [most countries in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#/media/File:DecimalSeparator.svg)